# How to monitor data transfer speed and volume between two computers on same network

Tags: performance, monitoring, zfs, local-area-network, zfsonlinux

My application on Win2012 Server stores its cache on a ZFS appliance in the local network, during peak load we are seeing some performance degradation, this only happens in the production environment where we don't have debugging access. All troubleshooting so far points to this network access but we can't pinpoint it for sure as we don't have any concrete evidence. My question: is there a way we can monitor this network data transfer using Perfmon or something else.

Comment: How ZFS was presented to Win2012? Is that physical or virtual server? Block or file level access to ZFS appliance?
Try to benchmark the networking and find out the bottleneck.

Comment: Win 2012 is a virtual server, file level access to ZFS appliance. I will be trying the benchmarking approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the enterprise manager to monitor the performance of the ZFS appliance and found that it is working properly. Performance problem was from a different part of the application.